# Is there a smooth tempered distribution $u$ such that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j} u(x-j)$ is not smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, singularity, schwartz-space, pseudo-differential-operators

I found the following claim in page 3 of

- *Weinstein, Alan*, [**A symbol class for some Schrödinger equations on ${\mathbb{R}}^ n$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2374454), Am. J. Math. 107, 1-21 (1985). [ZBL0574.35023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0574.35023):

> Operators whose symbols have bounded partial derivatives can move or even create singularities. For instance $e^{d/dx}$ is a translation operator with symbol $e^{i\xi}$, while **$\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j}e^{j d/dx}$ can act on a $C^\infty$ function in $\mathcal S'$ and produce a function which is not smooth**.

(emphasis mine). I can't see how this is true. Lets call $T=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j}e^{j d/dx}$. Obviously for a smooth function without the $\mathcal S'$ requirement, you can just take a function that grows too fast like $f(x)= 4^x$, then $Tf$ is not even finite. But attempts at an explicit counterexample in the relevant class  either don't belong to $\mathcal S'$(Weierstrass function) or end up smooth, since $2^{-j}$ decays geometrically.

If $Tf$ is not smooth, then $\chi Tf$ is not smooth for some cutoff $\chi\in C^\infty_c$. So we should be able to see this in the Fourier transform as slow decay. So in this line of attack, the game is to find $f$ so that
$$ F(\xi):=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j} (\hat\chi  * e^{ij\bullet}\hat f)(\xi)$$
has slow decay at infinity. But why should this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f(x)=\sin2^x$ function
$$
F(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}\sin2^{x+j}
$$
is bounded and continuous (and therefore belongs to $\mathcal S'$), but not smooth.

Comment: Oh, this is the 'Weierstrass' type example I had in mind, but I kept thinking that this is not tempered as its pointwise derivative isn't tempered. But that's OK as the distributional derivative isn't the pointwise derivative? is that right?

Comment: Yes, it defines a functional on $\mathcal S$ by integration, that's enough.

Comment: Thanks! (I for some reason cannot award the bounty on my phone, will try again when I get to my computer. At the very least positive score and accepted will automatically award it to you eventually)